# Time Comparison in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, time

I would like to compare a time string '09:12:00', within a given time interval ? 
Such as ,
T = '09:12:00';

if ( '03:00:00' < T < '05:00:00' ) 
end

Comment: Afaik 'a < b < c' should be written 'a < b & b < c'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply convert time strings to serial date number via [datenum](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html)

```
if ( datenum('03:00:00') < datenum(T) & datenum(T) < datenum('05:00:00') ) end
```

Comment: Thanks , I have just find the same function for the calculation. regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of existence of standard Matlab function that would do C-style comparison, as these user written function do: [lexcmp](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23035-lexcmp), [strcmpc](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23375-string-comparison) ...

It's not necessarily pretty, but you can do it with [sort](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html), [strcmp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) and [find](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html):

```
T = '09:12:00';

S = sort({'03:00:00', T, '05:00:00'});
F = find(strcmp(T, S));
if (1 == length(F) && 2 == F(1))
    % if T is  between given limits...
end
```